# Isomorphism of two $\operatorname{Hom}$ modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a ring (associative, commutative, with unity) and $I\subset R$ is an ideal. Let $M$ be an $R/I$-module and $N$ an $R$-module. Is it true that 
>   $$\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(M,\operatorname{Hom}(R/I,N))\ ?$$

I've tried to use some isomorphisms like $\operatorname{Hom}(R,N)\cong N$ but this doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: The left hand side of the equation does not make sense. How is $M$ and $R$-module?

Comment: We have a canonical epimorphism $\pi: R\to R/I$, so put $r\cdot m:=\pi(r)\cdot m$. It's quite standard construction (in Atiah & Macdonald, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By viewing $M$ as an $R$-module, you are in fact considering the $R$-module $M\otimes_{R/I}(R/I)$. Since the functor $?\otimes_{R/I}(R/I)$ is left adjoint to the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(R/I, ?)$, you get the isomorphism
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M\otimes_{R/I}(R/I), N) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(M, \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(R/I, N)).$$

Comment: Although $M\simeq M\otimes_{R/I}R/I$ is an isomorphism of $R/I$-modules and of $R$-modules as well, the sentence "*By viewing $M$ as an $R$-module, you are in fact considering the $R$-module $M\otimes_{R/I}(R/I)$.*" doesn't have much sense for me.

Comment: @user26857 By assumption, $M$ is an $R/I$-module.  Tensoring with $R/I$ (viewed as an $R/I-R$-bimodule) is a natural way to go from the category of $R/I$-modules to the category of $R$-modules.

Comment: @user26857 If you prefer: the projection $R\to R/I$ induces a functor from the category of $R/I$-modules to the category of $R$-modules; this functor is naturally isomorphic to $?\otimes_{R/I}(R/I)$.

Comment: This sounds better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy even from an more elementary point of view:

We have $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I,N) = \{n \in N \mid In=0 \} =: N[I]$ by the fundamental homomorphism theorem.

Now consider $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$. We have $If(M) = f(IM) = f(0)=0$, because $M$ is a $R/I$-module. This shows $f(M) \subset N[I]$, hence $f: M \to N$ is actually a map $M \to N[I]$, thus is an element of $\operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(M,N[I]) = \operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(M,\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I,N))$.

Comment: What says "*the fundamental homomorphism theorem*"?

Comment: That a morphism factors uniquely over $R/I$, if $I$ is contained in the kernel.